# Tatramajjhattatā • Equanimity • In the middle of all that

Tags: theravada, reference-request, sutras

Friends, could anybody direct me to some suttas of the pâli canon about **Tatramajjhattatā**, the developed form of the equanimous abiding 'in the middle of all that'.
To the best of my knowledge, this specific mental factor is mentioned in the ***Abhiddhamma*** and the ***Visuddhimagga***, but I was unable to find it referred to in the Pali Canon.

Many thanks for your much appreciated help, with Mettā

Comment: I don't think it is mentioned in Pali Canon, it seems the term was coined by Buddhaghosha. Do you mind providing quotes from Abh and Vsm? What this reminds me though is _ataraxia_ of Pyrrho, which was supposedly a concept he picked up from Buddhists in Northern India. ("In non-philosophical usage, the term was used to describe the ideal mental state for soldiers entering battle.") I wonder if Sarvastivadins had a similar concept... Perhaps Tattvasiddhi-Śāstra has something on the topic...

Comment: I think I heard these texts being mentioned in that talk : https://www.abhayagiri.org/talks/6179-in-the-middle-about-that but I fear I may be unable to provide specific quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Upekkhā word is used in [10 contexts](http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/attha_page.php?book=53&page=224&pages=3&edition=romanhttp://84000.org/tipitaka/read/attha_page.php?book=53&page=224&pages=3&edition=roman) of suttanta with 10 meaning, which were analysed by [sāriputta-aggasāvaka](https://unmixedtheravada.blogspot.com/search?q=s%C4%81riputta), then concluded to 4 sabhāva:

- One refers to vedanā (upekkhā-feeling).
- One refers to viriya (effort).
- Two refer to paññā (understanding).
- Six refer to tatramajjhattatā (equality/parity/counterbalance).

So, when sāriputta try to explain each upekkhā, he used the synonym words to explain them, like we saw in the dictionary, nowadays, such as in KN. Jūlaniddesa, [Udayamāṇavakapañhāniddeso](http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=30&A=4445):

> [446]    **Upekkhā**satisaṃsuddhanti   upekkhāti   yā   catutthajjhāne
>   *upekkhā*   upekkhanā   *ajjhupekkhanā*   cittasamatho   *cittappasādatā*  **majjhattatā   cittassa**.

**That is the original tatramajjhattatā in pāli cannon.**

### Why commentary concluded 10 meaning to 4 sabhāva?

Because of the main topic of each contexts, which each upekkhā word appearing. For the example in SN Mahāvagga, [First Ānandasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_item_s.php?book=19&item=1380&items=19):

> [1393]   Yasmiṃ   samaye   ānanda   bhikkhu  tathā  **samā**hitaṃ  cittaṃ
>   sādhukaṃ    **ajjhupekkhitā**    hoti   **upekkhāsambojjhaṅgo**   tasmiṃ   samaye
>   bhikkhuno   āraddho   hoti   **upekkhāsambojjhaṅgaṃ**   tasmiṃ   samaye  bhikkhu
>   Bhāveti   upekkhāsambojjhaṅgo   tasmiṃ   samaye  bhikkhuno  bhāvanāpāripūriṃ
>   gacchati.

You can see sama-word and ajjhupekkhā-word, which appeared in [Udayamāṇavakapañhāniddeso](http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=30&A=4445) like tataramajjhupekkhā, explaining **upekkhāsambojjhaṅgaṃ**. So, [commentary](http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/attha_page.php?book=53&page=224&pages=3&edition=roman) concluded them as the same type upekkhā, tattaramajjhupekkhā.